# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: string, kotlin, android-listview, integer

Click on Listview item set for the serachview then give Error
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String.

Code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
     val query : String = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
     searchView?.setQuery(query,true)
}
```

SearchAdapter.kt

```
 class SearchAdapter(val searchList : ArrayList<Search>, val context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return searchList.size
        }
    
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return searchList.get(position)
        }
    
        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }
    
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    
            val convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.textview_list,parent,false)
            val image = convertView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewHistory)
            val textView = convertView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_list_view)
            val imageClear = convertView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewClear)
            val search = searchList.get(position)
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_search_24)
            textView.text = search.search
    
            return convertView
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about using `.toString()`?

Comment: .toString() give Listview item ID is not give String

Answer (score 3):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val query : String = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            searchView?.setQuery(query,true)

}
```

Comment: .toString() give Listview item ID is not give String.

Comment: Try with this val query : Integer = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) or val query : Integer = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as Integer

Comment: but we want to listview item value not ID